# How to run tensorflow.js with Electron?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, electron, tensorflow.js

I can not run tensorflow.js with electron, please help. 
 
***What I have:*** 
 1. Windows 10 Version 1903 
 2. python 2.7 
 3. node 12.13.1 
 4. npm 6.13.1 
 5. node-pre-gyp 0.14.0, installed globally

***What I did:*** 
 1. Cloned electron-quick-start from Electron documentation (https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start). 
 2. Ran npm insntall and npm start to enshure everything works fine. 
 3. Installed @tensorflow/tfjs-node:

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0 install C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node 
> node scripts/install.js

CPU-windows-1.4.0.zip
* Downloading libtensorflow
[==============================] 2299069/bps 100% 0.0s
[==============================] 1212292/bps 100% 0.0s
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
+ @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.4.0
added 74 packages from 48 contributors and audited 256 packages in 30.48s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

4. Added line in preload.js

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

5. Ran npm start:

```
npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master
> electron .


 node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 5
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 5
```

And in app console:

```
Platform browser has already been set. Overwriting the platform with [object Object].
Environment.setPlatform @ C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\environment.js:38
init.ts:204 Unable to load preload script: C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\preload.js
(anonymous) @ init.ts:204
init.ts:205 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v4\tfjs_binding.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\preload.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:717)
    at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (reset-search-paths.ts:40)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:622)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\proxc\Desktop\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:66)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880)
```

***What I tried:*** 
1. Node version 13.3.0 
2. `npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source` 
3. Deleting node_modules and running scripts again 
4. Deleting the project and doing all over again

***May be interesting:*** 
1. `node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib` does not contain `napi-4`, but contains `napi-5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a known issue with the build of `tfjs-node` on Windows [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2370)

The solution would be to use node 10.16.3 and run the command:

```
npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source
```

Comment: Many thanks! I also noticed that Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 did not have MSBuild.exe in .../2019/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin and by switching to MVS 2017, using node 10.16.3 and running a command you provided my problem has been resolved